# How to explain the gam plot to a non-statisticians

Tags: interpretation, generalized-additive-model, smoothing

I have a GAM model to study the relationship between antibody titers at Cord (on the log scale) with the maternal antibody titers (on the log scale) and duration between vaccination and delivery.
After doing some data exploratory steps, I decided to fit a gam model.
This is my model:

```
gam.PT.Cord <- gam(logcordpt ~ logmumpt  + s(duration,k=4),data=datapt2)
```

The model diagnostics seem to give the indication that the model assumptions are ok. Please take a look at the plot:
 [image]

And now when I tried to interpret the effect of the duration (the smoothing term in my gam model), it is a little bit difficutl.
The plot is here:
[image]

Now what I am trying is: " The plot shows the change of the function of duration with regards to duration. Generally speaking, the more duration, the function f increases, hence increasing the Cord anti-FHA. The increase is more pronounced when it increases from 2 weeks to 8 weeks, and after that the increases stays more stable (difference between 8 weeks and 14 weeks is not really steep)."
Still I felt that my non-statisticians colleague not yet fully understood it. 
Any idea how to best explain this Figure to a non-statisticians?
Merci.

Comment: It really depends on the particulars of whoever you're talking to. Many people would be just fine with the picture, some would need  a bit of context about exactly what the picture represents. Others might need more handholding/guidance... but the precise form of additional guidance required will likely be different for different people.

Comment: You are right Glen.
But just for a short, quick interpretation. What would be the best way to make some one that does not have statistical background understand the message.
When I tried to explain it to my colleague, she got confused about the y-axis which in a frequent manual, should be the response variable. This is of course not true for this plot.

Comment: "what does the y-axis represent" is a much more specific - and more readily answerable - question

Comment: You could use the `shift` argument to add on the estimate for the model intercept, to at least scale the y-axis in a more intuitive sense. This would then be the estimate of the response given `duration` without considering the contribution from the `logmumpt` term. If your model didn't have the `logmumpt` term, the `shift` option would mean the y-axis was the response. With this other term, or more generally with other, possibly smooth, terms, these plots are showing a partial response.